# ns-3 simulator BulkSendApplication completion time?

Tags: c++, logging, ns-3

I set up a simulator where `N` slave nodes are sending data to a master node using `BulkSendApp`. The issue is that I can't seem to find how to log the completion time of the operation. I know about logging with the `prefix_time` flag (for instance)

`export 'NS_LOG=BulkSendApplication=level_all|prefix_func|prefix_time`

But this just logs all the packets. I only want the completion time.
Is there any way to get it without modifying the application class itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an easy and reasonably reliable way to accomplish this (welcoming comments).

1.
Add a pcap log to the sending nodes:

for me it was:

`csma.EnablePcapAll ("tcp-bulk-send", false);`.

`csma` is the helper I used to construct the switch topology. When this is enabled you get a .pcap file when you run the simulation.

2.
use `tcpdump -nn -tt -r tcp-bulk-send-N-D.pcap` (`N` = node index; `D` = device index)

This will print the relevant node's packet capture log. Now check when was the last ack received. You can also check how many packets were sent successfully (check how many were received on the other side) by making sure the application uses a unique socket port. The time when the last ack arrived is basically the needed completion time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trace source to notify you of the tx end events inside this application. It should however, be simple to add one, either as a trace source associated with the m_totBytes variable or as a traced callback. For example:

```
static TypeId BukSendApplication::GetTypeId (void)
{
  static TypeId tid = // ...
    // ...
    .AddTraceSource ("TotBytes",
                     "Total number of bytes sent",
                     MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&BukSendApplication::m_totBytes))
    ;
  return tid;
}
```

And:

```
void TotBytes (uint32_t oldval, uint32_t newval) {}

Config::ConnectWithoutContext (
  "/NodeList/0/ApplicationList/0/$ns3::BulkSendApplication/TotBytes",
  MakeCallback (&TotBytesTracer));
```

There is extensive documentation on this in the documentation as well: http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.19/manual/html/tracing.html#overview